# jQuery clone( ) to simulate shadow effect on IE7? (Or better ideas)?

Tags: jquery, clone

Can someone please help me with the jquery's `clone()` function?

Is there a way to duplicate a list (but only top level `li`s) and append it to itself. I want to make it look a shadow of the actual list because IE7 doesn't support shadows. I did try a few plug-ins but none worked perfectly, so I thought this might be a better way.

eg.
I want to generate a clone of the following but only top level

```
 <ul>
   <li>home</li>
   <li>about</li>
   <li>services
     <ul>
        <li>web</li>
        <li>grahpic</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
 <ul>
```

to generate another list without the sublevels.

```
 <ul>
   <li>home</li>
   <li>about</li>
   <li>services</li>
 <ul>
```

I tried

```
$('ul li').clone().appendTo('ul li');
```

but it gives a huge copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/JUtkm/1/

My solution (instead of trying to select top level LI's, I make `<span>` necessary for effect).

### HTML

```
<ul class="top">
   <li><span>home</span></li>
    <li><span>about</span></li>
    <li><span>services</span>
     <ul>
         <li>web</li>
        <li>grahpic</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
 <ul>
```

### jQuery

```
$('ul>li').each(function(i, e){
    var cloned = $(e).find('span').clone();
    $(e).append( cloned.addClass('li-shadow') );
});
```

### CSS

```
ul.top {position: relative;}
li {position: relative;}
li span {position: relative; z-index: 10; display: block; }
.li-shadow { color: rgb(130,130,130); position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; z-index: 5; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is going to help you create a shadow out of it. But I can say why you are getting a hug copy.

`ul li` selector will select all the `li` elements under `ul` and clone each of them and append into `ul li` which will again select all the `li` elements under ul.

You can try this code to clone just the top level items.

```
$('ul:first > li').clone().each(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').remove(); 
}).appendTo('ul:first');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zZGsT/)**

Comment: Thanks for such a prompt reply. Is it possible to just clone the top level list?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say first clone your current list and then remove the sublists

```
var clonedList = $('ul').clone()
clonedList.find('li ul').remove();
```

This should give you a new list without any sublists which you can append to the DOM where you want it.  I haven't tested it so it might need some tweaks but the idea should work.